Permission Dialog for Kotlin App not showing up
I am making an Android App with Kotlin for a College Assignment. The assignment has a requirement to store an image into an SQLite database. I code in the code to request permissions to access the phone gallery. However, when I test it out the request permissions dialog does not show up, but the code still works some what.
How do I know this? The toast that appears when the user denies permission shows up.
Here is the code I used:
Source Code:
package com.example.final_project

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat


class ItemAdder : AppCompatActivity() {

    u/SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.add_menu)

        val image_button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.image_button)

        image_button.setOnClickListener {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
                } else{
                    chooseImageGallery()
                }
            }else{
                chooseImageGallery()
            }
        }
       
    companion object {
        private val IMAGE_CHOOSE = 1000;
        private val PERMISSION_CODE = 10301;
        private val REQUEST_CODE = 13
    }

    private fun chooseImageGallery() {
        // This is irrelevant to the problem
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when(requestCode){
            PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    chooseImageGallery()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

Android Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemAdder"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
    </application>

</manifest>

Gradle Build:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.final_project"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.final_project"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.recyclerview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.recyclerview.selection)
    implementation(libs.androidx.cardview)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

I expected a permissions dialog to show up to select permissions, however the toast that says "Permission Denied" shows up immediately with no dialog box
I genuinely have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help.

When targeting android 13+ READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE no longer works and you must use a different permission
Please read the behavior changes
If the image is already on the device I am not sure why you would be storing it in a SQLite database, thats the opposite of what would be recommended and what you would normally do is just save the path to the file in the database. Also you should just need to use the photo picker then you dont need the permission

Photo Picker worked. I wasn't aware of this feature until you brought it up. Tysm.
